# how do i setup django in wamp?

Tags: python, django, wamp

I want to test my django app in my WAMP server. The idea is that i want to create a web app for aaa.com and aaa.co.uk, if the user enter the domain aaa.co.uk, my django app will serve the UK version, if the user go to aaa.com, the same django app will serve the US version (different frontend). Basically i will be detecting the host of the user and serve the correct templates.

How do i setup my WAMP so i can test this? right now i am using pyCharm default server which is 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: This tutorial was the first google result for "django in wamp": http://ericeastwood.com/blog/3/django-setup-for-wamp

Comment: I read that article before i published my question in stackoverflow, how do i setup the aaa.co.uk and aaa.com in the WAMP to test "hostname detection" to show different front-end for each request?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you did research before attempting to ask the question - sadly though, you've made no indication that you did so in your question. Sounds like you're interested in virtual hosts - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer is basically  ericeastwood.com/blog/3/django-setup-for-wamp  combined with httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html – shadow

Answer (score -1):

first install mysqliclient module using below command
pip install mysqlclient
open settings.py file and change database

```
    DATABASES = { 
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'yourdbname', 
        'USER': 'dbusername', 
        'PASSWORD': 'your password', 
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '3306', 
    } 
}
```

Comment: There's a MAJOR caveat here. In most Linux systems you'll have Python 3.x AND Python 2.7. As such pip will attempt to install on 2.7 (which won't help you with Python 3). You'll need to use pip3 to get it into Python 3,